# Jquery body from variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some jquery,

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    body=$(body).html;
    $("html").html(body);
});
```

Which should replace the document with it's body. But it doesn't work!

Comment: what you mean with 'it does not work'? no text replaced? text appended? error messages? different browsers produce the same result? besides that, adding the closing semicolon may be helpful.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You're just getting the current contents of the body re-adding it to the html element, the result will be the same?!?!

Comment: So that I could eventually get rid of a pages header

Comment: Looks like another [x-y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).   You want to get rid of the header, so decide to replace the body and ask how to do that - why not ask how to get rid of the header?  `$("#headerid").hide()`

Answer (score 2):

Despite I don't understand what you are trying to achieve, there are some errors in your code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var body = $('body').html();
    $("html").html(body);
});
```

1. `.html()` is a function so the *()* is needed
2. `body` is an html-tag so you need the `'` or `"` around the tag